# How can I put VMware VMs running on different computers on the same network?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have some (Windows) PCs. I have VMware (Workstation) on each PC. I want to run a VM on each PC such that all the VMs are on one network without the VMs having access to the network the PCs are on.

Can this be done? Do I need another VMware product? Is there an alternative with a similar outcome?

Comment: How would that be possible? If the VM's are on different computers how would they access each other except through the physical network? What product could connect these machines except over the physical network and how would that be possible?

Comment: You need a hypervisor that supports VLAN tagging, which I'n not sure if VMware workstation does.

Comment: @HBruijn: Yes, this would segregate the VM's from the other computers on the physical network but the VM's still need access to the physical network. I'm not sure if the OP means to segregate them as you stated could be done with VLAN's or if the OP means that they can't have any access to the physical network.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use vlans, use a utility VM on each server connected to the main network and form a vpn tunnel.  Then bridge the tunnel to the 2 virtual networks.  This will work when you don't have control over the intermediate network, eg. if it is the internet.

Comment: Please can you break this down into more steps for clarification?

Comment: I think too much detail is beyond the scope of this question but make 2 small linux vms with adapters on the real network and the virtual one, google "openvpn between networks". You can either ***bridge*** for them to look as one local network or give them 2 seperate subnets and ***route*** with each vm as the gateway of each private network

Comment: It's not clear what bridges to what.

Comment: 2 small linux vms with adapters on the real network <- yes, and the virtual one (which virtual one? A virtual network between the main VM and the utility VM?), bridge what, the virtual network and the real network? That's not what I want to do.